# Javascript Search Array for Object with a certain Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

i have an array of objects, looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "label": "anystring",
        "processowner": ["any name"],
        "withwhat": ["any text"],
        "withwho": ["any text"],
        "processstep": ["any text"],
        "cluster": ["anyValue1"]
    },
    {
        "label": "anystring",
        "processowner": ["any name"],
        "withwhat": ["any text"],
        "withwho": ["any text"],
        "processstep": ["any text"],
        "cluster": ["anyValue2"]
    },
    {
        "label": "anystring",
        "processowner": ["any name"],
        "withwhat": ["any text"],
        "withwho": ["any text"],
        "processstep": ["any text"],
        "cluster": ["anyValue1"]
    },
.........
]
```

The important Key, Value pair is `"cluster"`. It is possible that there are more objects with the same '"cluster"'-Value. What i want is a new Array with just the `"cluster"`-Value. But each only once! That's were im struggling.

What i did so far is looping over the given array and compare the current `"cluster"`-Value with a second(final) array `"tempNewJson"` (second loop) - filled with the first object `"initObj"` of the given array in it. If the Value is already in `"tempNewJson"` i want the code to do nothing. If the Value is not yet in `"tempNewJson"` i want to add it. But i still get duplicates and a wrong number of Values in my final array `"tempNewJson"`.

```
function convertJSON(initJson) {
var initObj = {};
initObj.title = initJson[0].cluster.toString();
initObj.scale = 6;
initObj.type = 'group-case-5-3';
initObj.children = [];
tempNewJson.push(initObj);
var contains = false;
// Schleife über alle Items in initialem JSON
for (var i = 0; i < initJson.length; i++) {
    // Schleife über bisher hinzugefügte Objekte in tempNewJSON
    contains = false;
     for(var j = 0; j < tempNewJson.length; j++) {
         contains = false;
         if(initJson[i].cluster.toString() === tempNewJson[j].title) {
             contains = true;
             console.log(initJson[i].cluster.toString());
             break;
         }
     }
     if(contains === false) {
            initObj.title = initJson[i].cluster.toString();
            console.log('test: ' + initJson[i].cluster.toString());
            tempNewJson.push(initObj);
     }
 }
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks.

The Output should look like this

```
["anyValue1", "anyValue2", .....]
```

I used Nina Scholz's answer like this:

```
var result = initJson.reduce(function (tempNewJson, initJson) {
    !~tempNewJson.indexOf(initJson.cluster) && tempNewJson.push(initJson.cluster.toString());
    return tempNewJson;
}, []);
 console.log(result);
```

What i get know ist the following array:

```
['anyValue1', 'anyValue2', 'anyValue1', 'anyValue3', 'anyValue1', .........
```

]

But what i want is:

```
['anyValue1', 'anyValue2', 'anyValue3', 'anyValue4', 'anyValue5', .........
```

]

Comment: I'm unclear on what the output should be; can you provide a sample?

Comment: I just updated my post @ExplosionPills

Comment: is cluster an array of strings?

Comment: if you use it `!~tempNewJson.indexOf(initJson.cluster) && tempNewJson.push(initJson.cluster.toString())` this way, then you need a `toString()` also in the `indexOf` part like `!~tempNewJson.indexOf(initJson.cluster.toString()) && tempNewJson.push(initJson.cluster.toString())`

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution with `Array.prototype.reduce`. The advantage of this method is the possibillity to return something (here an array) and take it as an input for the next iteration.

```js
var array = [{
        "label": "anystring",
        "cluster": "anyValue1"
    }, {
        "label": "anystring",
        "cluster": "anyValue2"
    }, {
        "label": "anystring",
        "cluster": "anyValue1"
    }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        !~r.indexOf(a.cluster) && r.push(a.cluster);
        return r;
    }, []);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This is short and works, but i still have duplicates in the result array.

Comment: @dnks23, please supply some more data.

Comment: tried to update my post above, does this help? dont know what else to provide.... @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 1):

If you can support it I would use [a `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```
let set = new Set;
initObj.map(item =>
    item.cluster.map(cluster => set.add(cluster))
);
```

Now `set` is an iterable with unique cluster values.

Otherwise you can do this with an array, but you have to do the unicity check on your own:

```
let newArr = [];
initObj.map(item =>
    item.cluser.map(cluster => {
        if (-1 === newArr.indexOf(cluster)) {
            newArr.push(cluster);
        }
    });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` and `filter()` for this.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "label": "anystring",
        "processowner": ["any name"],
        "withwhat": ["any text"],
        "withwho": ["any text"],
        "processstep": ["any text"],
        "cluster": ["anyValue1"]
    },
    {
        "label": "anystring",
        "processowner": ["any name"],
        "withwhat": ["any text"],
        "withwho": ["any text"],
        "processstep": ["any text"],
        "cluster": ["anyValue2"]
    },
    {
        "label": "anystring",
        "processowner": ["any name"],
        "withwhat": ["any text"],
        "withwho": ["any text"],
        "processstep": ["any text"],
        "cluster": ["anyValue1"]
    }
];

var clusters = data.map(function(item) {
    return item.cluster[0];
});

clusters = clusters.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return clusters.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

console.log(clusters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure JS to simply loop through your array and create a result object that contains all the objects with certain cluster keys, which creates a very useful object! The same thing is true for just getting your desired array of cluster names.

```js
// Simplified test object without all the value
var test = [
  {"id": 1,"cluster": ["anyValue1"]},
  {"id": 2,"cluster": ["anyValue2"]},
  {"id": 3,"cluster": ["anyValue1"]}
];

var result = {};
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  for(var c = 0; c < test[i].cluster.length; c++){
    result[test[i].cluster[c]] = result[test[i].cluster[c]] || [];
    result[test[i].cluster[c]].push(test[i]);
  }
}

document.write('<pre>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  for(var c = 0; c < test[i].cluster.length; c++){
    if(result.indexOf(test[i].cluster[c]) < 0)
      result.push(test[i].cluster[c])
  }
}

document.write('<br /><br />' + JSON.stringify(result));
document.write('</pre>');
```

Both objects could be very useful in their own way.